# AngularJS orderBy is not working with custom function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Currently, I have created the custom function to created to find the fromNow from the Moment and I want to sort the data based on the value returned by the function.

I want to put the Table Element at the Top for which **Days from Now** is lesser

In the below table **31 Days From Today** at the 2nd column is lesser and I want to put this element at the top, I have tried below way but it's not working

Can someone help me
**Table**

**[Table Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k6gz7m1m/1/)**

AngularJS OrderBy

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Holidays|orderBy:findFromNow">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Day}}</td>
                <td>
                <span class="label label-warning">{{findFromNow(x.Date)}} Days From Today</span></td>
                </tr>
```

Function

```
$scope.findFromNow = function (inputDate) {
        var m = moment(inputDate, "D-MMM-YY");
        var today = moment().startOf('day');
        var days = Math.round((today - m) / 86400000);
        if (days > 0) {
            return 999;
        } else {
            return (days * (-1));
        }

    }
```

Holidays JSON

```
  [
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "2-Jan-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "20-Feb-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "29-May-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "3-Jul-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Tuesday",
      "Date": "4-Jul-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "4-Sep-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Thursday",
      "Date": "23-Nov-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Friday",
      "Date": "24-Nov-17"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Monday",
      "Date": "25-Dec-17"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I don't use Angular, but I'd expect a custom sort comparator to take two arguments similar to using one with the standard array `.sort()`.

Comment: can you provide holidays array ?

Comment: @Akashii I have updated the question with all the details.

Comment: Yeah I have tried and I am getting as `NaN`

Comment: @Batman In fiddle I am not able to see your JavaScript code. Why?

Comment: @VicJordan I just created fiddle for Html table look

Comment: @Batman create full fiddle so that people can play around with code and provide you solution quickly

Comment: @VicJordan Sure I will create fiddle with js

Comment: @Batman you get `NaN` because in function orderBy , `inputDate` is Object not date

Comment: @Akashii sure let me check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write seperate function or check type of inputDate before use moment , because in orderBy , inputDate is Object not Date

```
 $scope.sortDate = function(inputDate){
    var m = moment(inputDate.Date, "D-MMM-YY");
    var today = moment().startOf('day');
    var days = Math.round((today - m) / 86400000);
    if (days > 0) {
        return 999;
    } else {
        return (days * (-1));
    }

}
```

Here is plnkr :

> http://plnkr.co/edit/afgsPDBF5RXG5WviYrdU?p=preview

Hope it help